# How can I make a simple api that can connect to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I need help on how to make an API for PHP. I was trying to make one web server communicate with another webserver through PHP.

I also want it to update MySQL code. I was using `$_GET` but it was less secure. Here is my code, can you please take a look at it?

```
<?php
/*
example: website-url-here.com/?command=insert-command-here&password=testing
*/
$command = $_GET["command"];
$password = $_GET["password"];
if ($password == "testing") {
//Was not a good idea, less secure.      
//echo eval($command);
//More secure
  if ($command == "create-user")
  {
   //create user command here
  } 
  else if ($command == "delete-user")
  {
   //delete user command here
  } 
  else
  {
  die("Command is incorrect");
  }
}
echo "Success";
?>
```

Comment: eval? are you some kind of crazy.

Comment: @Dagon It's like free access to a server :)

Comment: @Rizier123 ok cool please do this, i need another server to add to my botnet. it scans the internet for funny cat pics

Comment: Everyone's busting on you here and for good reason. **This is totally reckless** and should never, ever be done. Accepting and executing arbitrary PHP code via an API is completely the wrong way to go about it. If you want to do RPC, look at using a standard like [JSON-RPC](http://json-rpc.org/) to describe the operation you want done in a more abstract sense.

Comment: Have a read of this http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/ it's a fairly good resource for getting started with creating an API with PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is way too open ended to answer in a StackOverflow answer.  Try reading up a little on REST, and a lot on PDO, especially in the context of sanitizing user input.

Think about what would happen if somebody called your api  with `[url]?command=rm -rf .&password=testing`

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer

Comment: @Dagon It's probably the most concise possible answer given the question.

Comment: in that case, perhaps NOT answering is an option?

Comment: So you think I should not use eval and instead I should use something else.

Comment: What you've got in your edited post would function as a basic php API, and doesn't have any glaring security holes. Keep in mind that if you add any parameters to the query string, DO NOT blindly put then into a SQL query. Php's PDO class makes it pretty easy to stay safe from a SQL injection attack, so you might want to read those docs, they're not too long. Once you get going, you might want to look at some frameworks designed for making APIs, Slim or Silex are pretty easy.